# Design language or artifact for data science model

Tags: machine-learning, data-science-model, machine-learning-model

Inspired from this [question](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/12909/definition-of-a-model-in-machine-learning), given that there is no standard definition of a data-science model, is there a way to standardize the communication about any *data-science model*?

Just like *material design* is a *design language* to communicate a *UI design*, is there a *similar design* language to talk about ***data-science models*** as well?

Or any **other alternative** or **industry standard artifacts** that communicates intent, purpose, approach and design of *data-science model*?